# Library and sample used for Face Recognition and Face Crop in android

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv, face-detection, android

I need a library for Face detection and Face crop in android. please , Advice if anybody do this

Answer (score 0):

Do you check [OpenCV for Android SDK](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)?